# How to determine if it is the 15th of the month in a calendar table?

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table that contains all the dates (like a calendar). I want to run a query against it to return true if it is the 15th of the month. So for the dates in my calendar table, the day on which it is the 15th of the month value, I will get a TRUE back, otherwise FALSE. How do I do this? Extensive Google searches have not helped me with this puzzle. Does anyone here know?

Something like:

```
SELECT DAY, CASE_STATEMENT
FROM CAL
...
```

Comment: select case when datepart(day,getdate()) = 15 then 1 else 0 end as res

Comment: There is a [DAY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT [DAY],
       CASE WHEN DATEPART ( day , [DAY] ) = 15 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

Both [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)(day, [DAY]) and [DAY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)([DAY]) can be used. Using CASE is fine, but IIf is a little bit shorter.

Example:

```
SELECT [DAY], 
       IIF(DAY(Day) = 15, 1, 0) As IsItThe15th
FROM CAL
```

1 means True, 0 means False.